# Print Armstrong numbers between 1 to 10 million

Tags: perl

How to write a logic using `for` loop or `while` loop for printing [Armstrong numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number)?

Someone kindly explain how to print Armstrong numbers between 1 to 1,00,00,000.

This the algorithm that I followed

```
step 1 : initializing variable min,max,n,sum,r,t
step 2 : my $n = <>;
step 3 : to find base of $n
step 4 : using for loop 
        ( for (n = min; n < max ; n++ )
step 5 : some logic like 
        n=t,sum =0,r=t%10,t=n/10,
step 6 : 
        sum = sum + (n ^ base );
step 6 : 
        if ( sum == num ) print Armstrong numbers else not.
```

I tried to code this my code look like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

my $n;
chomp($n);

my $min = 1;
my $max = 10000000
my $r;
my $sum;
my $t;

my $base = length($n);
print "base is $base\n";

for ($n = $min; $n <= $max; $n++) {
  $t = $n;
  $sum = 0;
  while ($t != 0) {
    $r = $t % 10;
    $t = $t / 10;
    {
      $sum = $sum + ($base * $r);
    }
    if ($sum == $n) {
      print "$n\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How about you have an attempt yourself?

Comment: i tried to code this my code look like:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: this . #!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
my $n;
chomp($n);
my $min = 1;
my $max = 10000000
my $r;
my $sum;
my $t;
my $base = length($n);
print "base is $base\n";
for ( $n = $min; $n <= $max; $n++ )
{
$t = $n;
$sum = 0;
while ( $t != 0)
{
$r = $t % 10;
$t = $t / 10;
{ $sum = $sum + ($base * $r);
}
if ( $sum == $n)
{
print "$n\n";
}
}
}

Comment: i am doing blender some where i cant get it though

Comment: You should put your code in your question, not in a comment. Use the edit button. And also, you should explain the algorithm you are looking for, or link to it.

Comment: you have a small mistake in your code: `$sum = $sum + ($base * $r);` should be `$sum = $sum + ($base ** $r);` (when you wrote step 6 right)

Comment: i will check thank you paulchenkiller

Comment: tried by using $sum = $sum + ($base ** r) getting errors like :Uncaught exception from user code:
        syntax error at  line 11, near "my "
        Global symbol "$r" requires explicit package name at 
        Global symbol "$r" requires explicit package name at line 22.
        Global symbol "$r" requires explicit package name at ./amstrong1.pl line 24.

Comment: +1 because of ridiculous -1s, he's clearly shown an attempt to do this.

Comment: @Paulchenkiller thank you i checked it but i got errors Global symbol "$r" requires explicit package name

Comment: @helboy002 thats weird?!

Comment: The `chomp($n);` is useless; `$n` isn't even defined at that point (nor does anything you do later add a newline to it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things:

- It's bad practice to declare something with `my` until you need it.
- You must remember that numbers are also strings, and can be manipulated by string functions like `split`.
- C-like loops are discouraged in Perl because they're hard to read.
- Constants should be ...well... *constant*.

Here's my attempt. I use `split` to split up my digits into an array of digits. This is a lot easier than dividing constantly by ten. I can get the number of digits by simply taking the scalar value of my `@digits` array.

I can then loop through `@digits`, taking each one to the power of `$power` and adding it to `sum`. I use the `map` command for this loop, but I could have used another `for` loop too.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use constant {
    MIN             => 1,
    MAX             => 1_000_000,
};

for my $number ( (+MIN..+MAX) ) {
    my @digits = split //, $number;
    my $power = @digits;
    my $sum = 0;
    map { $sum += $_**$power } @digits;
    if ( $sum == $number ) {
        say "$number is an Armstrong number";
    }
}
```

And my output:

```
1 is an Armstrong number
2 is an Armstrong number
3 is an Armstrong number
4 is an Armstrong number
5 is an Armstrong number
6 is an Armstrong number
7 is an Armstrong number
8 is an Armstrong number
9 is an Armstrong number
153 is an Armstrong number
370 is an Armstrong number
371 is an Armstrong number
407 is an Armstrong number
1634 is an Armstrong number
8208 is an Armstrong number
9474 is an Armstrong number
54748 is an Armstrong number
92727 is an Armstrong number
93084 is an Armstrong number
548834 is an Armstrong number
```

Took a bit over five seconds to run.

Instead of `map`, I could have done this loop:

```
for my $digit ( @digits ) {
    $sum = $sum + ( $digit ** $power);
}
```

Comment: Sort of an aside, but "It's bad practice to declare something with my until you need it." -- I missed that rule.  I have a multi-decade habit of declaring variables up at the top of my programs.  Why is that bad?  Is it related to perl's being an interpreted language?

Comment: In early languages like Fortran and Pascal forced you to set aside for variable declarations at the beginning of the program which leads to the practice. In Perl, `my` variables are lexically scoped. They sprint into existence when needed and out of existence when no longer needed. Imagine a variable only used in a `while` loop. Every time I go through the loop, I get a new variable that has nothing to do with the variable before. When I leave the loop, the variable no longer exists. It means I can't accidentally use a meaningless variable.

Answer (score 0):

### Did this one at university...

I dug out the one I made in C and converted it to perl for you (it may *not* be the best way to do this, but it is the way I did it):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $min = 1;
my $max = 10000000;

for (my $number = $min; $number <= $max; $number++) {
    my @digits = split('', $number);
    my $sum = 0;
    foreach my $digit (@digits) {
        $sum += $digit**length($number);
    }
    if ($sum == $number) {
        print "$number\n";
    }
}
```

([Demo - 1 to 9999 due to execution time limit](https://eval.in/41386))

Comment: @helboy002 I revised it and fixed the warning, had a derp moment and split on `undef` instead of `''`.

Comment: is it possible to do with out using array and foreach ?

Comment: @helboy002 Why would you want to impose such a limit on yourself? Is this homework?

Comment: @helboy002 - Well could use `for` instead of `foreach` like my original C, but it's cleaner to use `foreach`.

As for doing without array, I'm sure you could but I don't know how. I'm still very much learning with perl.

Comment: @LightningDust `for` and `foreach` are exactly the same in Perl: They are actually aliases for each other. It is the syntax that makes the distinction.

Comment: @TLP Thanks, so it's not like PHP where `for` has significantly better performance?

Comment: @TLP yeah its actually a task for me have to do using for loop and while loop only.

Comment: @helboy002 Change the `foreach` loop to `for(my $count = 0; $count < length($number); $count++)`?

Comment: @TLP Don't know what policy here on homework is. I don't mind helping if people will read the code and understand it rather than just copy paste it.

Comment: @LightningDust When in doubt, [`Benchmark`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Benchmark) it.

Comment: @Lightning Dust yeah and also have to use while loop and it should not use split undef etc and mainly should not use Data::Dumper too

Comment: @helboy002 You don't need `Data::Dumper` for this, I accidentally left that in from debugging.

Comment: @Lightning Dust i figured it thank you anyway. actually i tried using for and while loop and my logic didn't work you can observe by looking above code. and the execution time very lengthy too.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be right, but you have some kind of problems with your start. For example you dont read from `STDIN` or from `@ARGV`. Would you do that, you just have a small problem with your calculating of the exponential calculation. In most Programming Languages, the syntax for a exponential calculation is `**` or a `pow()` function.
I really dont understand, for what this part is:

```
while ($t != 0) {
    $r = $t % 10;
    $t = $t / 10;
    {
      $sum = $sum + ($base * $r);
    }
    if ($sum == $n) {
      print "$n\n";
    }
}
```

For what is the naked block? Why do you use the modulus? .. Well i give you a small code for calculating the armstrong numbers with bases of `1..100`, between 0 and 10million:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
foreach my $base (0..100) {               # use the foreach loop as base
  for my $num (0..10_000_000) {           # and use numbers between this range
    my $ce=0;                             # ce = calculated exp.
    foreach my $num2 (split //,$num ) {   # split each number for calc each
      $ce += $num2 ** $base;              # exp. and adding it (see algorithm)
    }
    if ($num == $ce) {                    # when the exp. num and the number
      print "$base => $num\n";            # itself equals, its a armstrong number
    }                                     # print that
  }
}
```